# how to crate navigation menu for blogger via page list widget

Tags: html, xml, templates, layout, blogger

i'm creating blogger template and in that i have a side navigation menu. everything is perfect in navbar.

You can check it [Here](https://glassy-ui-template.blogspot.com/)

so, its a very simple navigation menu. but the navigation menu menu is not editable from blogger layout section and so for that i think i'll have to use widget like link list or page list.

whenever i try to do so all things get messed up.

And that is the problem. How? how can i embed blogger widget to my nav menu ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <b:section  maxwidgets='1' name='Main Menu' showaddelement='no'>
                <b:widget id='LinkList01' locked='true' title='Main Menu' type='LinkList' version='2' visible='true'>
                  <b:widget-settings>
                    <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>NONE</b:widget-setting>
                    <b:widget-setting name='text-1'><i class="material-icons">grid_view</i>Dashboard</b:widget-setting>
                    <b:widget-setting name='link-1'>/search/label/Dashboard</b:widget-setting>
                    <b:widget-setting name='text-2'><i class="material-icons">lightbulb</i>Technology</b:widget-setting>
                    <b:widget-setting name='link-2'>/search/label/Technology</b:widget-setting>
                    <b:widget-setting name='text-3'><i class="material-icons">rocket_launch</i>Science</b:widget-setting>
                    <b:widget-setting name='link-3'>/search/label/Science</b:widget-setting>
                    <b:widget-setting name='text-4'><i class="material-icons">perm_identity</i>About US</b:widget-setting>
                    <b:widget-setting name='link-4'>/search/label/About US</b:widget-setting>
                    <b:widget-setting name='text-5'><i class="material-icons">contact_page</i>Contact Us</b:widget-setting>
                    <b:widget-setting name='link-5'>/search/label/Contact Us</b:widget-setting>
                  </b:widget-settings>
                  <b:includable id='main'>
                    <b:include name='content'/>
                  </b:includable>
                  <b:includable id='content'>
                    <ul id='xcfsd-csvgList' role='menubar'>
                      <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'><li itemprop='name'><a expr:href='data:link.target' itemprop='url'><data:link.name/></a></li></b:loop>
                    </ul>
                  </b:includable>
                </b:widget>
    </b:section>
```

example: https://support.pipdig.co/articles/blogger-dropdown-menus/

Comment: how can i add icons to items ?